# Ring shaped div

Tags: html, css

Actually I have 2 questions here. I'll explain them as much as I can.

I'm trying to create a ring shaped div. Below is what it should look like.

[image]

[This](http://dabblet.com/gist/4571207) is what I have done so far. How can I get the slight curve from left bottom corner to the top? And how can I create the *inverted* curve for the right side?

Thank you.

Comment: that's not a ring, that looks like a segment of a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a second circle that whites-out the portion of the image you don't want to see.

For example, if you add a second div (inside the first) with id `cutout` and style it as follows:

```
#cutout {
    top:250px;
    border-radius: 700px;
    border:300px solid #eee;
    z-index:1;
    left:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Then in your image you'll get a little closer to what you want.  You'll also want to add `position: relative` to your container div to ensure that's what it's positioned and clipped to.

Finally, if you want clip the ring segment as shown in your image, you'll need to add an extra outer div just to clip the innermost two; and you should replace the image with a radial background.

That'd look approximately like: http://dabblet.com/gist/4571882

Image: [image: css-based-variant]

Honestly though, I'm not sure contortions like this work very well - you'll usually not get exactly the result you wanted, and it's likely not to work on older browsers very well; nor for that matter necessarily on newer browsers that implement a newer version of these CSS properties.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do this instead of using curved divs. If you have any suggestions please, I'm all ears. Thanks again.

Comment: On transparency: You cannot use a transparent cutout - the div will *always* be convex, so the only way to make it appear as if it had a inner curve is by putting something on top of it that has such a curve.

Comment: Alternatives: use an image; use an *svg* image (supported everywhere border radius is anyhow); use radial gradients with white+transparent bands (IE9 and lower don't support this); Use a huge canvas and a simple generative approach.  Svg might be best; canvas is sorta cool, but sounds more complex to do well.

Comment: Thank you. Although it will take me some time to do it that way as I haven't worked with SVGs and canvas until now.

Comment: Adobe Illustrator for instance supports SVG out, as I'm sure do lots of other programs, so you don't need to code the svg by hand - or you could at least start with a decent example that way.

Answer (score 0):

you could try creating a new div and adding

```
border-top-right-radius: XXX
```

for the inverted segment. Making sure they float correctly (e.g. `float:left`).